# Find a function h3(c) that will make $ (a, b, c) \mapsto 2^{a−1}3^{b−1}h_3(c)$ a bijection

Tags: number-theory

Find a function $h_3(c)$ that will make
$$g_3 : \Bbb N × \Bbb N × \Bbb N → \Bbb N, \qquad (a, b, c) \mapsto 2^{a−1}3^{b−1}h_3(c)$$
a bijection. Your $h_3(c)$ should be an increasing function, i.e. $h_3(c_2) > h_3(c_1)$ if $c_2 > c_1$, and may have a multi-part definition, i.e. of the form
$$
h_3(c) =\cases{h_3'(c) & if a certain condition is satisfied\\ h_3''(c) & otherwise}
$$

Comment: Any motivation behind this?

Comment: What do you think about the problem? What have you tried so far, and what are you stuck on?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at prime decompositions, then there is only one thing that $h_3(c)$ can be. It has to be the $c$'th natural number that is nether even nor divisible by $3$. This is because we want all natural numbers to be hit, and $2^{a-1}$ and $3^{b-1}$ can account for any power of $2$ and $3$ respectively. $h_3(c)$ therefore has to hit all the rest. We get
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
c & h_3(c)\\
\hline
1 & 1\\
2 & 5\\
3 & 7\\
4 & 11\\
5 & 13\\
6 & 17\\
7 & 19\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
If we look at when $c$ is even and when it's odd, we can see that on odd $c$'s, we get $3c -2$, and on the even ones we get $3c - 1$. There are multiple ways of writing down this function, but since you've been hinted to use a conditional definition, we can use that:
$$
h_3(c) = \cases{3c-2 & if $c$ is odd\\3c-1 & if $c$ is even}
$$
Other ways of expressing this same function includes
$$
h_3(c) = 3c - \frac{3 + (-1)^c}{2}\\
h_3(c) = \text{the $c$'th natural number divisible by neither $2$ nor $3$}\\
h_3(1) = 1, \quad h_3(2) = 5,\quad h_3(c) = h_3(c - 2) + 6\\
h_3(c) = 6\left\lfloor \frac c2\right\rfloor - (-1)^c
$$
Also note that $25$ is the first non-prime hit by this function, for $c = 9$.

Comment: I knew the function but was not sure how to write this function clearly but I guess this is how you do it!

Comment: @JackYoon If you already have something similar to my table, then there are two approaches to this problem. The first is to see if you can impose some simple condition. $c$ even or odd is the easiest, but in other cases it can just as well be $c$ prime, or $c$ a square, or something (you've already been given a hint that this might work, after all). Then see if what you have in each pile is simpler. The other is to simply enter it into [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+5%2C+7%2C+11%2C+13%2C+17%2C+19&language=english&go=Search)'s search function and see if your table pops up as a result.