# Find the increasing function where $g_4 : \mathbb N^4 \to\mathbb N$, $(a, b, c, d) \mapsto 2^{a−1}3^{b−1}5^{c−1}h_4(d)$

Tags: number-theory

A bijection
$g_4 : \mathbb N\times \mathbb N \times\mathbb N \times\mathbb N \to\mathbb N$, with $$(a, b, c, d) \mapsto 2^{a−1}3^{b−1}5^{c−1}h_4(d)$$
is constructed, with $h_4(d)$ as an increasing function. Find the values of $a, b, c, d$ such that

(i) $g_4(a, b, c, d) = 7236$

ii) $g_4(a, b, c, d) = 833$

Comment: I answered a [very similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268087/find-a-function-h3c-that-will-make-a-b-c-mapsto-2a%e2%88%9213b%e2%88%921h-3c-a/1268127#1268127) not an hour ago. Look at that answer, and see if you can adjust it to suit your needs.

Comment: What is that $7$ doing there?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews "7→" means $\mapsto$. Jimi, please use [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference') for formatting mathematics on this site in the future.

Comment: You don't really need to strictly "find" $h_4$.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm trying to find the function for h4(d) but I cannot see the pattern for the primes

Answer (score 1):

$h_4(d)$ is the $d$th smallest natural number which is not divisible by any of the primes $2,3,5$.

If $n$ is any natural number, then the number of numbers $m\leq n$ that is such that $\gcd(m,30)=1$ is:

$$d_4(n)=n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{n}{5}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{n}{6}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{n}{10}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{n}{15}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{n}{30}\right\rfloor$$

(That formula requires an inclusion/exclusion argument.) You can make this formula much easier by seeing that:

$$d_4(n+30)=d_4(n)+8,$$ so you only need to compute $d_4(n)$ for a small set of values less than $30$, and then get $d_4(n+30k)=d_4(n)+8k$. Since we only really care about the cases when $n$ is relatively prime to $30$, this means we really only need to know the eight values $$d_4(1)=1,d_4(7)=2,d_4(11)=3,d_4(13)=4,\\d_4(17)=5,d_4(19)=6,d_4(23)=7,d_4(29)=8$$

So, for example, if you are trying to find $d$ such that $h_4(d)=67$, you'd just need to compute $d_4(67)=d_4(7)+8\cdot 2$.

You could write a closed formula for $h_4$, I suppose, though it is ugly:

$$h_4(d)=\begin{cases}30\frac{d-1}{8} + 1=\frac{15d-11}{4}&d\equiv1\pmod 8\\
30\frac{d-2}{8} + 7=\frac{15d-2}{4}&d\equiv 2\pmod 8\\
30\frac{d-3}{8} + 11=\frac{15d-1}{4}&d\equiv 3\pmod 8\\
30\frac{d-4}{8} + 13=\frac{15d-8}{4}&d\equiv 4\pmod 8\\
30\frac{d-5}{8} + 17=\frac{15d-7}{4}&d\equiv 5\pmod 8\\
30\frac{d-6}{8} + 19=\frac{15d-14}{4}&d\equiv 6\pmod 8\\
30\frac{d-7}{8} + 23=\frac{15d-13}{4}&d\equiv 7\pmod 8\\
30\frac{d-8}{8} + 29=\frac{15d-4}{4}&d\equiv 0\pmod 8\\
\end{cases}$$

Or, slightly more succinctly:

$$h_4(d)=\begin{cases}
\left\lfloor\frac{15d}{4}\right\rfloor&d\equiv 2,3\pmod 8\\
\left\lfloor\frac{15d}{4}\right\rfloor-1&d\equiv 0,5\pmod 8\\
\left\lfloor\frac{15d}{4}\right\rfloor-2&d\equiv1,4\pmod 8\\
\left\lfloor\frac{15d}{4}\right\rfloor-3&d\equiv 6,7\pmod 8\\
\end{cases}$$